# How to pass an R function argument to select rows from a df

Tags: r, function, subset

I'm trying to write a function that will allow me to specify one or more values in column "x" of my df so that my result contains only the rows with those x values. I plan to add other arguments to the function later, but this is a first step.

```
x<-c(1:100)
y<-rnorm(100)
df<-as.data.frame(cbind(x,y))
myfunc<-function(x=1:100){
result<-subset(df,select=x)
result
}
```

When I run the following code to obtain a 4-row df, the result is 100 rows and only column x:

```
> myfunc(x==3:6)
      x
1     1
2     2
3     3
4     4
5     5
....
99   99
100 100
```

myfunc(x=3:6) and myfunc(3:6) don't work either

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd edit your function like so:

```
myfunc <- function(z = 1:100){
  result <- subset(df, x %in% z)
  result
}

myfunc(z = 3:6)
#   x          y
# 3 3  0.7585295
# 4 4 -0.2713343
# 5 5  0.5359432
# 6 6 -0.4653105
```

Comment: Having both a column and a function argument with the same name (`x`) is a recipe for disaster, so I chose `z` to differentiate them.